# How can I trigger keyboard commands via AppleScript in a Flash-generated upload prompt?

Tags: macos, flash, upload, safari, applescript

I'm trying to submit upload a photo to a website via AppleScript.

The basic experience is:

1. Load Site [done]
2. Click "Upload" [done - triggers Choose File prompt in what looks like the Finder, but still says Safari in top left]
3. Type file path in prompt and submit using:

   `tell application "System Events"
       keystroke "g" using {shift down, command down}
       keystroke "/Users/myUser/Pictures/myPic.jpg"
       key code 36
   end tell`

But instead the AppleScript just stops moving once the prompt appears, and waits for human interaction.  How can I use AppleScript to upload an image in a prompt like this?

Demo of the web side of things: http://www.uploadify.com/demos/

Assume I can click the "Select Files" button in this demo via AppleScript.  How can I continue to use AppleScript to enter the file path and submit?

Comment: Demo of similar web ux: http://www.uploadify.com/demos/

Comment: How are you clicking the upload button? As that code proceeds dealing with the dialog it's be worth showing.

Comment: Perhaps this is a just a matter of timing - try inserting a delay before sending the keystrokes (and perhaps also between the ⌘⇧-G command and typing the filename). Needless to say, this is not a robust solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need delays in the code like @mklement0 said
and to also make sure safari is activated

```
tell application "safari"
activate
    tell application "System Events"
        keystroke "g" using {shift down, command down}            
        delay 1.6
        keystroke "/Users/myUser/Pictures/myPic.jpg"
        delay 1.6
        key code 36
    end tell
end tell
```